# Как сделать валидации TextBox'а

Tags: asp.net, forms, c#, регулярные-выражения, vb.net

Как сделать валидации на TextBox в ASP.NET Forms, при помощи регулярного выражения, как в RoR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю точно про вебформы, но в MVC это делается через аттрибуты на свойствах моделей. Скорее всего это поможет:
[system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx)

Можно подключить даже клиентскую валидацию на JS.